# How to mock api authetication in laravel unit testing

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, authentication

`enter code here`I call service which requires authentication, for that, I Have used without middleware trait,

```
$user = new User([
            'id' => 1,
            'eos_id' => '832355',
            'user_name' => 'yish',
            'email_id' => 'test@test.com'
        ]);
        $this->actingAs($user, 'api');
```

after that when I check as auth('api')->check()  it always returns false.

EDIT

COntroller method that i want to test

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        try {
            $deleted = $this->wareHouseService->deleteWareHouse($id, auth('api')->user()->getAuthIdentifier());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $errors = [$e->getMessage()];
            if ($e instanceof ValidationException) {
                $errors = Arr::first(array_values($e->errors()));
            }
            return (new ErrorResource(collect($errors)))
                ->response()
                ->setStatusCode(422);
        }
}
```

Test method

```
public function test_destroy_warehoue () {

    $user = new User([
            'id' => 1,
            'whr_id' => '832355',
            'user_name' => 'yish',
            'email_id' => 'test@test.com'
        ]);

        $this->actingAs($user, 'api');

    $this->mockWareHouseService->shouldReceive('destroy')
            ->with(619, auth('api')->user()->getAuthIdentifier())
            ->andReturn(true);
    $actualData = $this->mockWareHouseController->destroy(619);

}
```

Here auth('api')->user()->getAuthIdentifier()  is aways return null .

Comment: it is not necesary to remove middlewares and when you remove middlewares you also removes auth

Comment: do you authenticate with passport?

Comment: if you are going to "unit" test a method, than it should not have anything related to middleware. If the method you are going to test has some lines something like `Auth::shouldReceive('check')->andReturn(true);` or `Auth::shouldReceive('user')->andReturn($user);` - if you provide the concrete method i may provide a better explanation.

Comment: @Ersoy I have updated my question,  hope you can understand with that example

Answer (score 0):

In your test method, you need to mock Auth class just like you mock your `wareHouseService`. When to user (after guard) is invoked it should return your user. It will be something like this;

```
$user = factory(User::class)->create(['id' => 2]);
Auth::shouldReceive('guard')->once()->with('api')->andReturnSelf();
Auth::shouldReceive('user')->once()->andReturn($user);
```